# C# Checkbox per model property

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, checkbox

I'm not sure if it is possible in a easy way (with little code that is).

I have a model:

```
public static Class TestClass
{
    public static bool Test1 { get; set; }
    public static bool Test2 { get; set; }
    public static bool Test3 { get; set; }
    public static bool Test4 { get; set; }
    public static bool Test5 { get; set; }
    public static bool Test6 { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible for a simple Foreach or other command to create 6 checkboxes, each named as the property name and checked bound to the actual property?

So basicly what I want to create this for each property:

```
var check = new CheckBox { Name = Test1 };
check.CheckedChanged += (s,ea) => { TestClass.Test1 = check.IsChecked; };
```

but for each property and perhaps even with less code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible but I dont know if you can do it with static properties.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public bool Test1 { get; set; }
    public bool Test2 { get; set; }
    public bool Test3 { get; set; }
}

void Test(Control parent, TestClass tc)
{
    int y = 10;

    foreach (var prop in tc.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var cb = new CheckBox(); 
        cb.Name = prop.Name;   
        cb.Text = prop.Name;
        cb.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Checked", tc, prop.Name));
        cb.Location = new Point(10, y);
        parent.Controls.Add(cb);
        y += 25;
    }
}
```

example:

```
{
    var form = new Form();
    var tc = new TestClass();
    tc.Test2 = true;
    Test(form, tc);
    form.Show();
}
```

Comment: Was looking for the "ClassName.GetType().GetProperties()". Thank you very much!

Comment: btw: Confirmed that it does not work for static classes since you need to make a instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in the old fashion way:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    CheckBox[] cbs;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cbs = new CheckBox[] { checkBox1, checkBox2 }; //put all in here
        for (int i = 0; i < cbs.Length; i++)
        {
            cbs[i].Name = "myCheckBox" + (i + 1);
            cbs[i].CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckBoxes_CheckedChanged);
        }
    }

    private void CheckBoxes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
        MessageBox.Show(cb.Name + " " + ((cb.Checked) ? " is checked" : "is not checked").ToString());
    }

    private void buttonStateAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (CheckBox cb in cbs)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(cb.Name + " " + ((cb.Checked) ? " is checked" : "is not checked").ToString());
        }
        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

This code will create an array of checkBoxes you want to have in array. Then it will show you message when ever you will click on one, or there is a button, which will give you the actual state of all checkBoxes.
I hope its in a help,
bye

Comment: This would mean I still have to make a line for each property.  I wish for it to do that "automaticly"

Comment: Why, isnt good a bit of code? It alctualyl faster then using Linq, and lambda expressions.

Comment: True but I want as little code as possible. "Speed" isn't a issue. Also i'm in a learning stage so I'm trying to find out different ways to do things. This is the most basic way and thus already in my knowlage. 
it is still a good way ofcourse, but not what I was looking for.